# HTTP GET of a live Camera stream and display it in picture box

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, ip-camera

I am having live url="http/ip:port/live.mp4?channel=0&type=0" Basically i want to get the live video stream(HTTP GET of live url) and display it in picture box. Program Blocks when i convert Stream to Bitmap.

```
 String url = String.Format("http://{0}/live.mp4?channel={1}&type={2}", ipAddress, channel, type); 
    Console.WriteLine(url);
    int read, total = 0;
    // Bitmap bmp = null;
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        var credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
        credentialCache.Add(
        new Uri(uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)), // request url's host
        "Digest",  // authentication type 
        new NetworkCredential(nvtUserName, nvtPassword) // credentials 
);

        httpWebRequest.Credentials = credentialCache;
        // httpWebRequest.ContentType = "video/mp4";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("cookie", cookie);
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-csrftoken", strcsrftoken);
        //httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "spider/1.0";

        httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
        Console.WriteLine(cookie);
        Console.WriteLine(strcsrftoken);

        var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine("Status code={0}", (int)webResponse.StatusCode);
        //var stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
        //   bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
        Stream output = new MemoryStream();
        using (Stream input = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            
            p.Image = Bitmap.FromStream(input); 
        }
```

Comment: but isn't it `mp4`? bitmap is one single image??

Comment: Then how to get the mp4 from the live view with get of live url?

Comment: You are using blocking API, so anything you'll do would block. Second, you are trying to get an image from a video stream. So the decoder is probably waiting on an "end-of-stream" which will never come. Read yourself into video streaming and follow the steps described there. Use async API where possible and make sure you can decode the stream. You may want to consider using a different UI Component that does part of that work for you.